Iterator over Vec<Vec<i32>>: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows
I'm writing a function to process Vec<Vec<i32>>:
fn process_grid(grid: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    grid.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(i, row)| {
            row.iter()
                .enumerate()
                 // closure may outlive the current function, 
                 // but it borrows `i`, which is owned by the current function
                .flat_map(|(j, val)| process(i, j, *val))
        })
        .collect()
}

fn process(i: usize, j: usize, val: i32) -> Option<i32> {
    todo!()
}

The full compile error looks as follow:
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `i`, which is owned by the current function
   --> src/main.rs:291:27
    |
291 |                 .flat_map(|(j, val)| process(i, j, *val))
    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^         - `i` is borrowed here
    |                           |
    |                           may outlive borrowed value `i`
    |
note: closure is returned here
   --> src/main.rs:289:13
    |
289 | /             row.iter()
290 | |                 .enumerate()
291 | |                 .flat_map(|(j, val)| process(i, j, *val))
    | |_________________________________________________________^
help: to force the closure to take ownership of `i` (and any other referenced variables), use the `move` keyword
    |
291 |                 .flat_map(move |(j, val)| process(i, j, *val))
    |                           ++++

Adding the move keyword indeed make things work, but it didn't make it clear on why it does not compile without move.

How is it even possible the closure |(j, val)| process(i, j, *val) may outlive its enclosing closure:
|(i, row)| {
    row.iter()
        .enumerate()
        // closure may outlive the current function, 
        // but it borrows `i`, which is owned by the current function
        .flat_map(|(j, val)| process(i, j, *val))
}

Maybe placing explicit lifetime would help here?

The compiler has chosen that the closure in question only references i, and since that is captured by reference and iterators are lazy, this will effectively try to return a reference to i from the outer flat_map closure, which isn't allowed since i only exists for that call.
In this case it is sufficient to tell the compiler to move captures into the closure by adding the move keyword like so:
fn process_grid(grid: Vec<Vec<i32>>) -> Vec<i32> {
    grid.iter()
        .enumerate()
        .flat_map(|(i, row)| {
            row.iter()
                .enumerate()
                .flat_map(move |(j, val)| process(i, j, *val))
                //        ^^^^
        })
        .collect()
}

